# Compare 6 columns and return non identical value

Tags: excel, vba

I think I need a macro for what I would like to accomplish. I have 3 columns on sheet 1 and 2, but I would like to compare them and return a list under sheet 3 that has no duplicates and keeps track of the changes.

Sheet1 (New):

```
Count     State     City
1         MO        STL
2         MO        STP
1         FL        Tampa
1         FL        Ft. L
```

Sheet2 (Old):

```
Count     State     City
7         MO        STL
6         MO        STP
5         FL        Tampa
4         TX        Hston
```

Sheet3:

```
 State     City    CountNew     CountOld 
 MO        STL     1            7
 MO        STP     2            6
 FL        Tampa   1            5
 FL        Ft.L    1            
 TX        Hston                4
```

So far what I have accomplished has not help me and I cant find any other case with a situation like this one. I was trying to do this through formulas, but quickly realized thatall I was able to do was transfer the values of the columns from sheet 1 and 2, to sheet 3. But I was not able to accommodate the cell values that differ (Houston and Fort Lauderdale).

Would appreciate any help.
Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far, formula can do this also what did you try?

Comment: What I have so far is doing on sheet3 the following:
For Column State = Sheet1!B2
For Column City = Sheet1!C2
For Column Count New = Sheet1!A2
For Column Count Old = Sheet2!A2

But clearly that doesn't do anything for the values that change or are different in Sheet 2.

Answer (score 0):

An idea would be something along these lines for finding uniques with a State & City helper column or add more to check the 2 columns?

In sheet1 and sheet 2 have a = `State & "_" & City`

In Sheet 3, A1 you can have `=Sheet1!A1`
and in A2 you can have `=Sheet2!A1`

then filled down from A3, you can have the following array formula

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A2:$A$10,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(Sheet3!$A$1:$A2,Sheet1!$A2:$A$10),0),1),INDEX(Sheet2!$A2:$A$10,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(Sheet3!$A$1:$A2,Sheet2!$A2:$A$10),0),1)),"")
```

This will give you the uniques across the 2 tabs, for normal lookups off the unique helper columns

Comment: Thanks for that formula. It helps to an extent, sheet 1 and sheet two can change at any moment. Since their values are based on different web queries. It just happens to be that the query on sheet 1 sometimes matches some of the cells of query in sheet 2. Basically sheet 1 is the information found on an x website at time y. Sheet 2 is the same website but at a different time; therefore, the cell values may change. In a sense sheet 3 is dynamically changing depending on whatever shows up in sheet 1 and 2.

Comment: I am still struggling with what I need to accomplish. I think it would help me a lot if somebody can help me achieve get on sheet 3 max number of the State mentioned among the two sheets. Ex.

Sheet1:
State     
MO        
MO        
FL        
FL
NV

Sheet2:
State     
MO        
MO        
FL        
TX
NV
NV
 
Sheet3:
State     
MO        
MO        
FL
FL
TX
NV
NV